# Change the object (car) speed

Tags: function, math, lua, love2d

I need to change the object speed after I changed his rotation.

```
function love.update(dt)

if car['speed'] > 0 then
    car['x'] = car['x'] + math.cos(car['angle'])
    car['y'] = car['y'] + math.sin(car['angle'])
end

if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
    car['speed'] = car['speed'] + dt
end

if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
    car['angle'] = car['angle'] - (1 * dt)
end

if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
    car['angle'] = car['angle'] + (1 * dt)
end
end
```

After I changing the speed in the "w" I want it to change the speed of the car (x,y).
But when I trying to add the speed its just changing the rotation and ruining it..

Answer (score 2):

The required change is very simple: just scale the `cos` and `sin` by the car speed:

```
if car['speed'] > 0 then
    car['x'] = car['x'] + car['speed'] * math.cos(car['angle'])
    car['y'] = car['y'] + car['speed'] * math.sin(car['angle'])
end
```

Also, in Lua, `car['speed']` is equivalent to `car.speed` ([syntactic sugar](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.2)). Some people find this easier to read. The code above could be written as:

```
if car.speed > 0 then
    car.x = car.x + car.speed * math.cos(car.angle)
    car.y = car.y + car.speed * math.sin(car.angle)
end
```

PS: Don't forget to slow down the car ;)